# Automiating Oracle SQL Developer Installation

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When installing Oracle SQL Developer (after having already installed Java JDK), the first run of Developer requests to "Please specify the path to the Java JDK home".There are no problems selecting the JDK folder manually, however I am wanting to automate this part of installation/initial start-up.

Setting Environment Variables JAVA_HOME and/or PATH to the JDK location (or the bin folder) does not alleviate the dialogue.

**Is there a way to automate the selection of the JDK folder during installation / before first run of Oracle SQL Developer?**
Otherwise is there a location, the value input into this dialogue is stored?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/12/oracle-sql-developer-4-windows-and-the-jdk/), it appears that as of Oracle SQL Developer Version 4, "...to accommodate shared Windows machines, we now look into the roaming profiles directory in the Application Data folder". By running a batch file to edit / automate writing the installed Java path into this file, it is possible to automate the initial dialogue box (well, make it disappear).